# Pressing back key does not wait for animation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

When the user shift pages in my application, simple animation should fade out items before shifting, but it's not working and going for the shift immediately.

Code:

```
        public PageClass()
        {
            BackKeyPress += OnBackKeyPressed;
        }

        void OnBackKeyPressed(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var control in ContentPanel.Children)
                MainPage.FadeOutObject(control);

            var translation = new TranslateTransform();

            PageTitle.RenderTransform = translation;

            var s = new Storyboard();
            Storyboard.SetTarget(s, translation);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(s, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.YProperty));

            s.Children.Add(
                    new DoubleAnimation()
                    {
                        From = -300,
                        To = 0,
                        Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0)),
                        EasingFunction = new PowerEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut }
                    });

            s.Begin();

            s.Completed += (object sd, EventArgs ea) =>
            {
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }; 
        }
```

Now, this does not work, it goes back to the MainPage straight away, does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `e.Cancel` to stop the previous page from being handled automatically, since you're already telling it which page it should go to.

```
void OnBackKeyPressed(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;

    foreach (var control in ContentPanel.Children)
            MainPage.FadeOutObject(control);

    //...rest of your code
}
```